# Funny behavior of Ellipsoid function

Tags: functions

From its [description](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/MultivariateStatistics/ref/Ellipsoid.html) I thought that the normalizations of the directions `d_i` of the semi-axes did not matter when using the `Ellipsoid` function. Indeed, the following two commands give the same output:

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"];
Graphics[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], Axes -> True]
Graphics[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {{0, 100}, {100, 0}}], Axes -> True]
```

However, if the normalization of the two directions is different, I get a funny behavior. Basically, the radii are multiplied by the normalization of the first direction vector. Use for example:

```
Graphics[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {{0, 100}, {1, 0}}], Axes -> True]
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the details of how the third argument of `Ellipsoid` is processed by inspecting the code which is available in the package `MultiDescriptiveStatistics.m`.

```
nb = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Packages", 
 "MultivariateStatistics"}, "MultiDescriptiveStatistics.m"]];
NotebookFind[nb, "Ellipsoid[mu_?VectorQ, r_?VectorQ, dir_?MatrixQ]"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the parameters like this (see documentation):

```
Graphics[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {100, 200}, {0, 1}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Parameter 1: Center
Parameter 2: Radii
Parameter 3: Direction

**EDIT**

If you work with vectors, please consider:

```
Show[Graphics[Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {100, 200}, {1, 0.5}], Axes -> True], 
 Graphics@Arrow[{{-100, 200}, {100, -200}}]]
```

[image]

I'm afraid you have to do some arithmetic to get `{100, 200}, {1, 0.5}` from `{{-100, 200}, {100, -200}}`

Comment: thanks, but i need to use vectors as directions (which may not be aligned with the axes)

Comment: Did you find this syntax in the documentation? Where? Also, how do you generalize this syntax to three dimensions?

Comment: @Valerio [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RegressionCommon/ref/Ellipsoid.html)